# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 160

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

This code is basically adding binary numbers. For some reason I keep getting an index out of bounds error on line
102 which is the nested `for` loop `if` statement towards the bottom. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Process {

  private String storeString="", x="";
  private String polynomial;

  //get file 
  public void getFileName(String fileName) {                        
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) { 
      String sCurrentLine="";

      while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {  
        storeString+= sCurrentLine.toUpperCase();
      }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Sorry no such file is was found!" +
                         "\n\nAre you sure that's the right file name");
    }   
    System.out.println(storeString);

    if (storeString.matches("[0-9A-F]+") == true) {
      System.out.println("true");
      hexToBin(storeString);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Sorry that is an Invalid Hex");
      System.exit(0);
    }       
    System.out.println(x);

  }

  //convert to binary       
  public void hexToBin(String hex) {
    String bin = "";
    String binFragment = "";
    int iHex;
    hex = hex.trim();
    hex = hex.replaceFirst("0x", "");

    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
      iHex = Integer.parseInt(""+hex.charAt(i),16);
      binFragment = Integer.toBinaryString(iHex);

      while (binFragment.length() < 4) {
        binFragment = "0" + binFragment;
      }
      bin += binFragment;
    }
    System.out.println("length:" + bin.length());
    Calculate(bin.length(), bin);
  }

  // calculations
  public void Calculate(int size, String hex) {
    char [] poly= new char[17];
    char [] charBin= new char[size];
    int move=-1,zero=0,L=0;

    polynomial = "10000100110001101";

    //convert to char
    for (int i=0; i < 17; i++) {
      poly[i] = polynomial.charAt(i);
    }
    //convert hex to char
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
      charBin[i] = hex.charAt(i);
    }

    //compare with if statements
    for (int i=0; i < size ; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j < 17; j++) {
        move++;
        if (charBin[move]=='1' && poly[j]=='1') {
          charBin[move] = '0';
        } else if (charBin[move]=='0' && poly[j]=='0') {
          charBin[move] = '0';
        } else {
          charBin[move] = '1';
        }
      }

      int k=0;
      //print charbin
      //while (charBin[k]!= size) {
      //  System.out.print(charBin[k]);
      //  k++;
      //}

    }//end class

  }//end class

}
```

Comment: Please, post the stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you loop `i` up to `size` and `j` up to 17 and increment `move` each time, you can expect `move` to get up to `17 * size - 1`. You are using it to index into an array of length equal to `size`.

```
char[] charBin = new char[size];
int move = -1;
...
for(int i=0;i < size ; i++) {
   for(int j=0;j < 17;j++) {
      move++;
      if(charBin[move]) ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome so If I reset move I should no longer get this error ?

Answer (score 2):

`charBin` has `size` locations. But you are accessing its values in your loop using `move` as an index. `move` is being incremented every time inside your second loop:

```
char[] charBin = new char[size];
int move = -1;
for(int i=0;i < size ; i++) {
    ...
    for(int j=0;j < 17;j++) {
        ...
        move++;
    }
}
```

In the outer loop `i` runs from `0` to `size` and in the inner loop `j` runs from `0` to `17`. `move` therefore has a potential maximum value of `size * 17`. As soon as `move` becomes the same value as `size`, you will get an exception since you are outside the bounds of the array (valid locations in `charBin` run from `0` to `size - 1`).